# Silverlight 4.0: Cross Domain Policy Error

Tags: web-services, silverlight-4.0, asmx, crossdomain.xml, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I have a webservice and a Silverlight application.
I also have a crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml

```
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

here my cross domain policy

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy 
  SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="http://localhost/MHVWS/MachineHistoryWS.asmx" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

My web service is being hosted in IIS.

With this configuration I still have this kind of error:

> An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://localhost/MHVWS/MachineHistoryWS.asmx'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

- You only need one policy file. You dont require both.
- Be sure one (or both) of those policy files exist in the same location (domain) as the webservice.
- To debug and see what is going on, use a tool like Fiddler to verify the url path of the policy xml file the client is looking for.